# Getting Max(Date) out of Similar Dates

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table which has the following Columns

TransDate(varchar20) , Name(varchar20), Address(varchar20), Amount(int), Balance(int)

Now i need to get "Recent Balance" which i am getting using the following Query

```
Select Balance from myTable where TransDate = (Select Max(TransDate) from myTable)
```

This query is giving me proper result if there is only one entry per day like below

```
10/12/2010   SomeName   SomeAddress   1000   1000
10/13/2010   SomeName   SomeAddress   1000   2000
10/14/2010   SomeName   SomeAddress   1000   3000
```

But what if i have more than 1 entries per day as shown below?

```
10/12/2010   SomeName   SomeAddress   1000   1000
10/12/2010   SomeName   SomeAddress   1000   2000
10/12/2010   SomeName   SomeAddress   1000   3000
```

How to get the "most recent balance" using the above date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies. I got it working

Below is the query that worked for me

```
Select Balance from myTable where TimeStamp = (select MAX(TimeStamp) as RecentTime from myTable where RecordDate = (Select MAX(RecordDate) from myTable)   Group By RecordDate
```

BTW i added another column to myTable named TimeStamp so that i get to know which is the latest Date amongst the Similar Dates

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
  Sum(Balance)
from myTable 
where TransDate = (Select Max(TransDate) from myTable)
```

If you want the balance for each day

```
Select 
  TransDate,
  Sum(Balance)
from myTable 
Group By TransDate
```

Answer (score 1):

As the date format doesn't give the last time stamp, you can't rely on it for the last balance. Instead, use the sum of the amount field :

```
Select 
  Sum(Amount)
from myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

If in database you have no real indicator of what is the latest of three records, it is impossible to say which is the latest - you need to change something so that time also gets stored, not just date.

If you need just any of the records for the last day, you can `SELECT TOP 1`, if you need the sum - see Sajib Mahmud or John Hartsock answers

**UPDATE**

If `Balance` is actually a sum of `Amounts`, then just select the sum of `Amounts`, no matter what `Balance` values are.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually Balance is not just adding the Amount, it depends upon the condition of my Software (developed in VB.net). If some condition is true, Amount is added to Balance and if some condition is false, the Amount will be subtracted, so `Sum(Amount)` wont work i guess. As you said, i think i need to have timestamp stored in my table also.